# Scala access or pass dataframe within udf

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

UDF - I have to traverse through the dataframe to perform certain operation. I do understand that I cannot access the complete dataset in udf. But what is the solution to this?

```
def process(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame): DataFrame = { 

    def udf_func = udf((name: String, cluster_id: String) => {
    print(df.count()) <-- thisline   
    cluster_id     
})
val newdf = df.withColumn("cluster_id", udf_func(df("name"),df("cluster_id")))
```

I need to traverse 'name' through all the names of the dataframe and get levenshtein distance, if it is within a threadshold, I update the cluster_id

print(df.count()) --> Demo only - just to show that I cannot access df within the UDF

Comment: Why not do the count outside the UDF? If you want to do a count of number of rows with same name/cluster_id then you are looking for `groupBy`.

Comment: I don't understand the df.count() because it's a like a costant in udf. Maybe are you looking for the row number associated to column cluster_id ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have mentioned that I placed df.count() just to show that I cannot access df. I have updated my question.

@Shaido - I cannot do group by as I need to group by closest match.

Comment: @EyediaTech Of you want to compare the value of every row with values in all other rows you would need to  `crossJoin` the dataframe with itself.